# I cant run any command for vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm-cache

I am trying to create a new project in vue, but I always get this error.
I have tried to uninstall node and install it again..
I have tried `npm cache clean --force`.
I have tried to create it using "vue-ui".
I have tried to change the directory but always get this error any one help please.

#### Error Log:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...lize-package-data"],"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-18T10_53_43_155Z-debug.log
```

Comment: what command are you trying to run? vue create projectname? Did you try to reinstall the vue cli?

Comment: vue create "myProject", for example,  Torsten Kolb.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar issue regarding node and npm today.

What worked is as follows:

1. **npm cache clean --f did not work for me either**. Hence, I deleted the "npm" and "npm-cache" folders from the location C:\Users\SearchYourUserName\AppData\Roaming
2. Uninstalled the existing node.
3. I needed node version v10.x.x. I downloaded the node-v10.22.1-x64.msi file from https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/ and installed it.